# Jenkins throws: Connection to Nexus refused error?

Tags: maven, connection, jenkins, nexus

We are using Maven deploy Plugin and Jenkins can not deploy and throws Exception? 
Locally it works(console).
Why is that?

jenkins error:

```
 Could not transfer artifact XX:XYZ from/to nexus (http://10.0.0.0:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): Connection to http: //10.0.0.0:8081 refused
```

for download e.g. a dependency jar from the Nexus Jenkins throws the same error

Comment: Connection to http://10.0.0.0:8081 refused

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a firewall that is blocking traffic to IP address 10.0.0.0 on port 8081.

Comment: the Error comes after a few seconds. Jenkins can donloaden e.g. a Jar File (at the most). It can not be of firewall, because Jenkins load e.g. a Jar and not more...and and .. I think mybe on timeout...

Comment: Either a timeout or possibly a threshold on download size